# Efficient way to filter array of Person objects based on an array of string names

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, comparison

I have an array of names:

```
var namesArray = ["Bert","Tony","Phil","George", "David"]
```

I then have an array of Person Objects:

```
var personsArray: [Person]
```

And a snippet of my Person class is:

```
class Person {
    var name: String

 ...some code omitted...
}
```

I am looking for a way to filter my array of Persons objects to only include the `Person` whos name is found in the `namesArray`.

I considered using the `.filter` on the array but I need to loop over two arrays.

```
 let filterByNameArray =  persons.filter({
    ($0.name == //string)!
  })
```

But I believe this is incorrect as I need to loop through the names array also. I solved my issue using a double for loop:

```
 var pArray: [Person] = []

  for person in personsArray {

    for nameString in namesArray {
      if person.name == nameString {
        pArray.append(person)
      }
    }
  }
```

However, this is ugly and uses a significant amount of CPU so my question is,is there a more efficient way to do this? :) Im sure there is.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you subclass `NSObject`?

Comment: @TimVermeulen no problem, I subclass `NSObject` so I can compare one `Person` object to another.

Comment: Don't do that. Implement the `Equatable` protocol instead.

Comment: @TimVermeulen thanks for the tip. Im just beginning Swift at the moment so I have plenty to learn. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `contains` method on the `namesArray` to search all of it.

```
let filteredByNameArray = persons.filter {
  namesArray.contains($0.name)
}
```